# Запустить скрипт от имени пользователя. WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

В коде плагина есть условие

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
add_action('...')
}
```

При запуске функции срабатывает хук плагина, при условии, что её запустил пользователь.

Когда функцию запускает wp-cron, хук не срабатывает.

Как можно запустить хук посредством wp-cron?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в functions.php

```
if( wp_doing_cron() ) {
    add_action(...);
}
```

Comment: я не могу вызвать эту функцию плагина прикрепленную к хуку, из functions.php

Comment: Почему? Она что, метод объекта в плагине? Вы же код не показали, как я могу догадаться?